# eval() namespace alias not working

Tags: php, namespaces, eval

I have the following code:

```
<?php
namespace namespace1{

    function hi()
    {
        echo 'hi';
    }

    hi();

}
namespace {

    eval( 'use namespace1 as nm1;' ); // does not work

    // use namespace1 as nm1; // works

    nm1\hi();

}
```

and receive the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function nm1\hi()

Is there a reason why I cannot `eval()` the namespace alias construct?

It seems to be behaving as if I was trying to achieve this via `include`.

Additionally, is there any way to achieve namespace aliasing without directly declaring it within the file which uses it?

Comment: I would have thought `eval()` was a runtime thing, so when PHP tries to load this file and syntax check it, the namespace won't be set till the code is run.